# code with PDO not working it's not return 'user_id'

Tags: php, pdo

I am implimenting RBAC system but prlomlem cant get id and store in session 
    in the following code error at :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\CRM\login.php on line 19

### Here is my code block:

```
<?php 
require('connection.inc.php');

require_once "Role.class.php";
require_once "User.class.php";

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['userpwd'];

if(!empty($username) )  //   && $_SESSION['username'] == ''
{

    try
    {
        $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare('SELECT `user_id` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = :username');

        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if (count($result)) 
        {
            foreach ($result as $row) 
            {
                echo $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "No rows returned.";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    { 
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"]))
    {
        $user = new User($_SESSION["user_id"]);

        if ($user->hasPermission("permission"))
        {
            //This user is allowed to do this
            header("Location: dashbord.php");
            exit();
        }

        if ($user->hasPermission("no_permission"))
        {
            //This user is NOT allowed to do this
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }   
}
else
{
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('ERROR:Please enter your username and password');
    //window.location=".html";
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: i try also by this way but nothing happen  try{
        $query ="SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";

        $result = $dbhandle->query($query);


         while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   
            echo $row['user_id'];

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
   }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getMessage();}

Comment: You have no variable named `$id` in that code (as Saty pointed out) – and with proper `error_reporting` configured PHP would have told you that already. So see to it that you go configure that _now_ please.

Comment: If you prepare, shouldn't you like bind your username variabe?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() for PDO

Comment: yes, sorry about that for session but even it's not echo the 'user_id'

Comment: Please post your connection code too . This piece of information is in sufficient to understand your problem.

Comment: Well, I can tell already when it executes the file it's missing the username variable, since its not defined in this part, so aybe its good to show us where you defined username. Also I would bind the username as well to use the prepare statement to the fullest.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the value you are searching for, and check for if you get rows returned.

```
$stmt = $this->db->conn->prepare('SELECT `user_id` FROM `user` WHERE `username`=:username');
$stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (count($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo $row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    }
} else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
}
```

Comment: it gives me "No rows returned." but i have username

Comment: Echo the username in the try statement to see if it is actually existing as what you think it is, and then check the database to make sure it is in the database.

Comment: yes username is echoing in try block and also it is in the database here require('connection.inc.php')      <?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "test";

try{
  //connection to the database
  $dbhandle = new PDO("mysql:$hostname;$db", $username, $password);
}

catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>

Comment: Matt you're missing an equal sign between username and :username

Comment: Oh, I wrote this too fast, haha. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE-1:**

First update your **connection.inc.php** file as below:

```
<?php 
  $hostname = "localhost"; 
  $username = "root"; 
  $password = ""; 
  $db = "test"; 
  try{ //connection to the database

    // you missed 'mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname'.
    $dbhandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password); 
  } 
  catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } 
?>
```

Now, Your **main query page :**

```
try{
  $query ="SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = ?";

  $stmt = $dbhandle->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $username ); // bind the username
  $stmt->execute();   // execute query
  // returning rows form database
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['user_id']; // echo to varify the row data
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; // can not understand why you make session for each user_id
  }
}
catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Comment: for this block of a code it gives me..                Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: @Kd01, you missed some equalities in **connection.inc.php**. So I update my answer.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: @Kd01, its working code. I tested on my localhost and then posted.